# links error what is wrong?

Tags: html, css

Why the links below works in Mozilla Firefox but don't work in Google Chrome? Any problems in my code and how to fix it?

```
<select>
 <option onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/');"> Example1</option>
 <option onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/');"> Example2 </option>
 <option onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/'); " >Example3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it is not with me why ?

Comment: when i click on it nothing happen

Comment: where is your link that u shared i cant find it

Comment: [http://fiddlesalad.com/html/](http://fiddlesalad.com/html/)

Comment: i try but the same result it work on mozilla and dosent work on chrome

Comment: is your chrome updated?

Comment: yes i update it right now and the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work only if saved in .html file. not on some online editor

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.open( this.options[this.selectedIndex].value));">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
<option value="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
```

Comment: window.open to make it open in new tab. try my updated script